# How to set NHibernate session to eager fetch

Tags: nhibernate

I've got a method helper in my tests base class that looks like this:

```
protected TEntity Fetch<TEntity>(Guid id) where TEntity : Entity
{
    using (var session = GetSession())
        return session.Get<TEntity>(id);
}
```

So I can call it from an integration test as such:

```
var persistedFoo = Fetch<Foo>(foo.Id);
```

How can I set the session in my Fetch method to eager fetch all properties in TEntity?

Answer (score 1):

According to NHibernate docs [here](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/lazy-loading-eager-loading.aspx) you should use NHibernateUtility class, so change your code into something like this should help:

```
using(var session = GetSession())
{
    var entity = session.Get<TEntity>(id);
    NHibernateUtil.Initialize(entity);   
}
```

Comment: Good to know about NHibernateUtil. Your answer sounds promising, but it doesn't quite work as you suggested. Per the docs you linked to, you have to actually specify the prop you want to initialize (e.g.: NHibernateUtil.Initialize(foo.Bars) // would initialize the Bars collection in foo). In my case, the Fetch method doesn't know TEntity's props so I can't use this approach. I could use reflection to solve it, but was hoping there was a more straight-forward option.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can use one of nHib's querying APIs (I personally prefer QueryOver), to do something like
`session.QueryOver<Cat>().Where(cat => cat.Id == id).Fetch(c => c.Kittens).Eager`.
This gives you the added bonus of controlling exactly which properties / collections would be fetched.

Also, it's recommended that you do NOT abstract-away your `ISession` usage in repositories.
It would prevent you from benefiting from such nHibernate features as batching (see ayende's post [here](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton))

Comment: As I mentioned on my comment to Hadi's answer, the problem is that in my case Fetch() is generic, so it doesn't know what type it's dealing with. Hence, I can't apply the .Fetch(c => c.Kittens) approach.

Comment: if you've read the post i've linked to (and several others by the same author), I think you'd be convinced that you don't actually need any of that. What you're actually trying to accomplish here is to build another level of abstraction on top of nHibernate. I believe that this is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I know what you mean. As I mentioned in my question, this is just a "convenience" method for unit testing. This is by no means to be used in application code.